# How do you assign values to structure elements in a List in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, data-structures

I have a user-defined structure in a list that I am trying to change the value for in an individual element within the list of structures.  Accessing the element is not a problem. However, when I try to update the value, the compiler complains:

> "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of the
>   assignment"

For example:

```
Public Structure Person

    Dim first as String
    Dim last as String
    Dim age as Integer

End Structure
```

_

```
Public Sub ListTest()

    Dim newPerson as Person

    Dim records as List (Of Person)
    records = new List (Of Person)

    person.first = "Yogi"
    person.last = "bear"
    person.age = 35

    records.Add(person)
    records(0).first = "Papa"  ' <<== Causes the error
End Sub
```

Comment: Every .NET programmer makes this mistake once.  A Structure is a value type, records(0) returns a *copy*.  Updating the "first" member of the copy doesn't accomplish anything.  Person needs to be a Class.

Comment: Darn carry-over assumptions from c++ ;).  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Hans: yeah, it is easy to forget that even `records(0)` will return a copy of the struct ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the other comments said, when you refer to records(0), you get a copy of the struct since it is a value type.  What you can do (if you can't change it to a Class) is something like this:

```
Dim p As Person = records(0)
p.first = "Papa"
records(0) = p
```

Although, I think it's just easier to use a Class.

Comment: Just ran into this problem because I had a dictionary with the value being a structure rather than class. Thanks for the simple solution!!

Comment: The problem with this is it copies the entire structure instead of just the pointer to it.  That's why you have to copy it back.  Double whammy.  Lot of overhead.

Comment: @Brain2000 - Agreed, but when using value types, you don't have much choice.  `Person` should have been a class not only for this reason, but also because mutable structures are discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually *two* important concepts to remember here.

One is that, as Hans and [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126318/how-do-you-assign-values-to-structure-elements-in-a-list-in-vb-net/7127834#7127834) have pointed out, `Structure Person` declares a **value type** of which *copies* are passed between method calls.

You can still access (i.e., get *and* set) the members of a value type, though. After all, *this* works:

```
Dim people(0) As Person
people(0).first = "Yogi"
people(0).last = "Bear"
people(0).age = 35
```

So the *other* important point to realize is that `records(0)` accesses the `List(Of Person)` class's special `Item` **property**, which is a sugary wrapper around two method calls (a getter and setter). It is *not* a direct array access; if it were (i.e., if `records` were an array), your original code would actually have worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by adding a simple Sub to the structure that changes the value of the property.

```
Public Structure Person

 Dim first as String
 Dim last as String
 Dim age as Integer

 Public Sub ChangeFirst(value as String)
  me.first = value
 End Sub

End Structure
```